# MACRO to concatinate __FILE and __LINE__ with formatting

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

I have used macros in  following way in my .cpp file named Test.cpp which is present in the location c:\Test\Test.cpp

Inside test.cpp

```
#define FILE_NAME strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__
#define S1(x) #x
#define S2(x) S1(x)    
#define LOCATION FILE_NAME " : " S2(__LINE__)
//#define LOCATION __FILE__" : " S2(__LINE__) Working but giving the whole file path where as i need only Filename:Line number

Inside Function 
{
  ::MessageBox(NULL,LOCATION,"Test",MB_OK); //Here i am getting only Filename .
}
```

Please help me in writing a MACRO so that i can get both Filename(Not the full path , only Filename) and Line number in my application .

Comment: No , it prints from messagebox line only .

Answer (score 2):

You try to concatenate string literal with the result of strrchr. This is not feasible. You will need a helper function, something like

```
std::string get_location(const std::string& file, int line)
{
  std::ostringstream ostr;
  size_t bspos = file.find_last_of('\\');
  if (bspos != std::string::npos)
    ostr << file.substr(bspos + 1) << " : " << line;
  else
    ostr << file << " : " << line;
  return ostr.str();
}

#define LOCATION (get_location(__FILE__, __LINE__))
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same through macro only ?

Comment: It should be doable with definiing macro returning `std::string` and then concatenating using `+` with colon and the line number. But I do not see any advantage over using a function.

Comment: I tried but unable to do it . Can you please help me in this ?

Comment: Here you go, but this code searches twice for backslash:

    #define FILE_NAME (strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? std::string(strrchr(__FILE__, '\\')+1) : std::string(__FILE__))

    #define LOCATION (FILE_NAME + " : " + std::to_string(__LINE__))

Comment: `std::to_string` was added in C++11, maybe you use a compiler without C++11 support. Write then your own `to_string` in similar way as in the code in the answer.